# escaping slashes in output using powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Im using powershell and Im trying to convert this to a JSON but the problem is a need to double all the slashes. So the `\` need to be turned into `\\` and `\\` needs to be replaced by `\\\\` in the output. Im using powershell using the following script:

```
$array = @()
echo "{"; echo '"data":['; (get-counter "\Processor(*)\% Idle Time").CounterSamples.Path | %{ $array += '{ "{#CPUID}":"'+ $_.TrimStart("$LowerCaseComputerName") }
for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length - 1; $i++){ $array[$i] + '"},' }
$array[$array.Length - 1] + '"}'
echo "]" ; echo "}";
```

and the output im getting is right except the slashes need to be doubled:

```
{  
"data":[  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(0)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(1)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(2)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(3)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(4)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(5)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(6)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(7)\% idle time"},  
{ "{#CPUID}":"\\aaronmartinez\processor(_total)\% idle time"}  
]  
}
```

Comment: it's just a string, basically.w hy not capture the string instaed of echoing it, then doing a simple string replace of ``\ -> \\``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a simple `-Replace '\\','\\'` and be done with it. The first `'\\'` is regex so the `\` is escaped to be `\\`. It would look like this:

```
$array = @()
"{"
'"data":['
(get-counter "\Processor(*)\% Idle Time").CounterSamples.Path | %{ $array += '{ "{#CPUID}":"'+ $_.TrimStart("$LowerCaseComputerName") }
for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length - 1; $i++){ ($array[$i] -replace '\\','\\')+ '"},' }
($array[$array.Length - 1] -Replace '\\','\\')+ '"}'
"]" 
"}"
```

**Edit:** While that does answer your question, a better solution in my opinion would be to correctly form the objects and use the convertto-json cmdlet.

```
$object = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{'Data'=@()}
(get-counter "\Processor(*)\% Idle Time").CounterSamples.Path | %{ $Object.data += [pscustomobject]@{'#CPUID'= $_.TrimStart("$LowerCaseComputerName") }}
$object | ConvertTo-Json
```

That gives you the same results I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in PowerShell v3 there is a cmdlet `ConvertTo-Json` for converting data structures to JSON format. You might find that easier than handcrafting like this. The `{`characters make string formatting very messy.